# Proxy Server for Android - Handling HTTPS

Tags: android, ssl, https, proxy

I've build proxy server for Android that captures all HTTP request. I also receive HTTPS in which I'm not interested but I just want to pass them through.

According to http://muffin.doit.org/docs/rfc/tunneling_ssl.html
when SSL connection is coming through proxy the HTTP method is CONNECT. For this I send response to client:

```
            if (request.startsWith("CONNECT")) {
            proxyOutputStream.write(("HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established" + CRLF + CRLF).getBytes());
            proxyOutputStream.flush();
```

and then I enable bidirectional connection:

```
                DirectionalConnectionHandler client = new DirectionalConnectionHandler(mProxySocket, mOutsideSocket);
            client.start();
            DirectionalConnectionHandler server = new DirectionalConnectionHandler(mOutsideSocket, mProxySocket);
            server.start();
```

However "Connection established" causes "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" error in browser.
If I don't send "Connection established" response the error is ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

What should be done to enable normal HTTPS connection and don't break browser ?

Comment: You need to establish the upstream connection first. Then deliver its success or failure status to the client. At present you're just lying to the client that the connect has succeeded when you haven't even tried it yet.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need response `HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established` in proxy mode.

Remove the following code,

```
proxyOutputStream.write(("HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established" + CRLF + CRLF).getBytes());
proxyOutputStream.flush();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Then I stay with ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED.

Comment: @Mogsdad It does not provide a *correct* answer to the question. [RFC 2817](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2817.txt) clearly states that there is a response to the CONNECT command,